If two complete orthonormal bases $x_n, y_n$ of $H$ are close when $n\gg1$, can the number of vectors 'at the start' be different?
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and suppose $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ and $\{y_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ are two distinct (disjoint as sets) complete orthonormal bases with the following property: there exists $c$ such that
$$ x_n - y_{n+c} \to 0.$$
Does it follow that $c=0$?
I originally thought the convergence forces $c=0$ and $x_n=y_n$, but I can construct a pair of distinct bases with $c=0$. My construction is just choosing a bunch of small rotations in a way that doesn't break the orthonormality: let $x_n$ be a given complete orthonormal set, choose a sequence $\epsilon_n>0$ with $\sum_n \epsilon_n < \infty$,  and construct $\{y_{n,m}\}_{n\ge0,\\0\le m\le n}$ as follows.
Put $y_{0,0} = x_0$. To inductively construct $\{y_{n+1,m}\}_{m\le n+1}$ from $\{y_{n,m}\}_{m\le n}$, first set $y_{n+1,n+1} = x_{n+1}$. To get $\{y_{n+1,m}\}_{m\le n}$, let $R_n^\theta$ be a rotation by $\theta$ radians of $\operatorname{span}(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})$ that fixes $x_{n+1}$, and put $y_{n+1,m} = R_n^{\epsilon_n} y_{n,m}$. To finish, we define $y_n := \lim_{m\to\infty} y_{n,m}$. It follows that there is some $C>0$ such that $|x_n - y_n| \le C\sum_{k\ge n} \epsilon_k \to 0$.
In addition, a minor variant (rotating around $x_{n+2}$) shows that we can achieve $\operatorname{span}(x_1,\dots,x_n) \neq \operatorname{span}(y_1,\dots,y_n) $ for each $n$.
